# Is there a way to disable/remove baseline profile from generating APK?

Tags: android, xposed, baseline-profile

I'm developing an Xposed plugin that only has a few classes. I don't think it's necessary to use the Baseline profile, but I can't find a way to disable it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simply delete the files in the file-system?

Comment: Not just a `baseline.prof` file, I found a Provider and a Receiver in my APK too.

Comment: I would try to just delete everything unnecessary. BTW: Are you developing the Xposed module in Kotlin? I am not sure if this is a good idea as the Xposed modules are included into the app VM, so class conflicts may arise.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it. As for writing Xposed modules in Kotlin, I haven't seen any flaws since both Java and Kotlin will eventually be converted to dex, so I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: The self-written Kotlin code should not be a problem but the DEX converted Kotlin code needs the Kotlin runtime libraries (just look at the APK size and you will see that the APK contains much more than just your code. And I am not sure what happens if the app the module is injected into also has those Kotlin libraries in a different version...